# FLASH Cannot access a parameter of superclass

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, inheritance, parameters

This throws an object unidentfied error on user.id

```
if (this.users)
            {    
                params.USER = [];
                for each (var user:UserObject in this.users)
                {
                    (params.USER as Array).push({id: user.id});
                }
            }
```

UserObject extends User. When I use User, everything works well.

UserObject is really simple, imports are alright.

```
public class UserObject extends User
{
    public var isSelected:Boolean;
}
```

How can I get the id parameter from the UserObject class without changing the instance of User?

Thank you very much guys

**EDIT:**

Let's simplify it then.

```
var user:UserObject = new UserObject;
user.id = '2';                        //this line shows the error
```

Where the User class has a public property id:String and UserObject extends User.

Comment: We cannot see anything from the code you posted /we don't know what params is, what this.users is, etc.). Please post all the relevant parts.

Comment: it has to be public, protected or private is not enough.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I simplified it. The reason I posted this is that I was forced to move to AS from java and have not that much experience. This should be well beyond correct in java, but I'm not sure what the thing is with AS.. it looks so simple, yet it doesn't work

Comment: You have to post the User code as well. Perhaps user.id is not accessible from its children.